# Determining if DEM has z values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, spatial-analyst, 3d-analyst, arcscene

How do I know if the DEM contains z-values?

I am looking at the DEM's layer properties and it does not mention the z values.

I then add it to ArcScene and tried to find it without success.

It only shows the x,y values.

Comment: @PROBERT, when you identify a pixel does it give you the elevation value?

Comment: Yes, if you open attribute values it tells you but what about the z value ?

Comment: @PROBERT, the z-value is the elevation value.  Is there a particular task you are wanting to do with these values?

Comment: No particular but Are all DEM suppose to have their z-values within the data ?

Comment: the dem without an elevation (z value) would not really even be a raster. in a raster you have the xy-s then you have a value (in picture rasters that would be a color value) In dems (which are just a raster with elevation) you have a value used for z. if the value doesn't represent z or if it is missing - that would IMO be no raster. I would also think tha tmost all software would throw an error with such a file.  @PROBERT - I think you probably have a value in your dem.

Comment: Brad, no problem I hear you. Just had to make sure about the z values. I am awared that all DEM has their x,y values in it but not sure of z values.  Thanks.

Comment: Brad, I think I figure it out about the z values. Here's the screen shot[z-values screen shot](http://hhhfvq.bay.livefilestore.com/y1p3D0GZ8r96MUyYsK4KSiTvVdm6A1RRDYJ8YiBFJsaNtCalD4tmOw0SsZC8BU7O7J7O3cXp35-1symH6mwI62022hGsbyPIf-h/z-values.png?psid=1) Your thoughts ? Take care

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should see a value which the image is stretched by when you add it to ArcMap, as in this:

[image: screen shot]

Then by switching to stretch type min-max you will see a more accurate elev value, as in this:

[image: Screen shot2]

which produces this:

[image: Screen shot3]

A nice touch then is to use the USGS color palette to show elev.

[image: USGS]

For this:

[image: DEM Elev]

Comment: Furthermore, you might need to "Add Statistics" so that the raster can be scaled to the correct range.

Comment: When you select the min-max it asks if you want to allow histograms to be built. I think it uses the statistics from that and that is how it shows the correct min-max. but I assume statistics would work for other raster functions.